Why parented cloth doesn't move with animated object?
I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SFeBQ9iubo&lc=UgwPCCRITRW7HZdauOZ4AaABAg.A3LJIhGpw8VA3QivdsyDde&ab_channel=BlenderRookie when a problem occurred to me. At final step, when I'm trying to parent empty with cape to already animated object, it doesn't follow the movement. I dug up all Internet searching for the solution to my problem, but nothing seems to work. Please, can anyone help?
Here's blender file: 
EDIT: 
EDIT 2: Updated file: 
EDIT 3: File after correction: 

In the video, Suzanne is not parented to an armature, while in your file your object is, the armature will move the mesh of your object but won't move the origin and therefore won't move the cape. What you need is either:

Parent the cape to the neck bone (or a bone that is around the neck).
Or parent the cape to 3 vertices of the Retopo_sweter (select the cape, shift select the Retopo_sweter object, switch to Edit mode, select 3 of its vertices and CtrlP > Make Vertex Parent).

Edit: First thing put your armature on Rest Pose:

Parent the cape to 3 vertices of your Retopo_sweter object:

Don't forget to activate the Self Collisions option of the cape. Also extend a bit the pin group. And play with some parameters, maybe lower donw the Speed Multiplier below 1, etc:

Quick try:


Thank you for your answer. Could you explain more precisely what do you mean by "select 3 of its vertices"? Does it have to be some specific vertices or just 3 random points?

Not 3 random vertices  the 3 vertices that will make a triangle and the child will follow its movements and rotations

Ok, I parented it, but the angle is quite weird. I'll update my post and add a screenshot. Could you tell me how to fix this?

Please share your last file

Here you go //

Sorry, I don't know why but I did everything you said about and it still parents under this same, weird angle. Maybe I misunderstood something. I uploaded a file, if you need it.

Put your armature in Rest pose before parenting the cape to the Retopo_sweter object, also choose a Speed Multiplier value lower than 1, not 12. I hope it fixes the problem?

Yes, it finally works! Thank you so much!
